# How can I make an image appear to flow seamlessly between tableview cells

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a UITableView cell with an image that spans the full height of the cell.

If I do not use a separator the images on each cell join up and appear as a single image, however, when I turn on the separator the image is sliced (see below). Is there a way to make the image appear on top of the table view separator?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would just get rid of the standard separator and manually draw a line beneath the image. This will probably simulate the separator quite nicely without it overlapping the image.

Perhaps just use an UIImageView with a stretched line image?

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but this line is only drawn on the cells that have data, which means that for a small number of rows you end up with a large empty area with no lines

Comment: If the line is beneath your image, and spans entire length of the cell, it will be visible when your image is not shown for cells with no data..

Comment: Exactly, just add the image of the line to all the cells and it will display in all the cells, even if there is no data in it.

Comment: For the line to be drawn, the cellForRowAtIndexpath will need to be called for each cell. The empty area that I mean are the other rows without data in them. If what you mean is that I fake the drawing of cells so that the view fills up with 'data' cells and 'line' cells, it's not exactly what I was looking for. I was hoping that there is some way to draw the image 'on top' of the line